# Is there a limit to the number of records Jira exports to RSS feeds?

Tags: spreadsheet, jira

I am trying to link a Jira query to a Google Spreadsheet using the =importXML() function. I have  about 1400 items that come back from the query, but they won't load into the spreadsheet. Though expermenting I found I could sent the maxlimit to 335, but not to 336.

The formula I am using is:

```
=ImportXML("http://jira.MyCompany.com:9100/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-xml/12183/SearchRequest-12183.xml?tempMax=335&os_username=ME&os_password=MyPASSWORD","/rss/channel/item/type")
```

There does not seem to be a data limit, if I change the "type" to "summary" I still have the same limit on the number of items.

Is there a Jira setting to override this? Or is a limit of Google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Limiting+the+number+of+issues+returned+from+a+search+view+such+as+an+RSS+feed

Information on Google Docs size limits are available here http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=37603